# Dynamically Load Angular2 Modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have created an Angular2 application, I am bundling this by using Webapack.
Now the destination file size got increased more than 15MB including depending modules.

Now I want to load dependency modules based on the demand.

I have multiple main menu's, each menu contains a module with related components. Now I would like to asynchronously load a dependency module based on user menu selection.

Comment: Have a look at this - everything you ever wanted to know about code splitting and lazy loading from Todd Motto. https://toddmotto.com/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311283/2545680) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using dynamic module loading and JIT compiler. Here is the general approach:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector, private compiler: Compiler)

loadModule(moduleName) {
    import(pathToModule).then((module)=>{
        const moduleClass = module.moduleName;
        const moduleFactory = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(moduleClass);
        const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
        const componentFactoryResolver = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver;

        // then you can use the resolver to get components
        const f = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
    })
}
```

Read more about dynamic components int the [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)